# Disconnecting pull chain from ceiling fan to install Lutron 'Maestro' fan/light switch

Tags: ceiling-fan

I installed a Lutron 'Maestro' fan/light wall switch (adjustable/dimmer) for a Hudson Bay fan with light.  The instructions recommend 'disconnect pull chains' ... The fan operates currently at just one speed (high) ...

There is a capacitor attached to the pull chain switch, do I disconnect that too?

Do I need to by-pass or splice wires?

Comment: Does this mean I put the fan on the lowest setting, middle or highest with the pull chain?  The wall switch doesn't seem to affect the speed.

Answer (score 3):

Step 15 of [these](http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/0301526.pdf) instructions suggest disconnecting (removing) the pull chain *extentions*, meaning the extra length of chain hanging down for convenience.  It doesn't suggest disconnecting the switch itself (i.e. no internal fan re-wiring is needed).

FWIW - Lutrons instructions are very easy to misinterpret in this step, I can see how you arrived at this point.